# CPU Ray Casting

Tags: c++, opengl, volume, raycasting, octree

I'm attempting ray casting an octree on the CPU (I know the GPU is better, but I'm unable to get that working at this time, I believe my octree texture is created incorrectly).

I understand what needs to be done, and so far I cast a ray for each pixel, and check if that ray intersects any nodes within the octree. If it does and the node is not a leaf node, I check if the ray intersects it's child nodes. I keep doing this until a leaf node is hit. Once a leaf node is hit, I get the colour for that node.

My question is, what is the best way to draw this to the screen? Currently im storing the colours in an array and drawing them with glDrawPixels, but this does not produce correct results, with gaps in the renderings, as well as the projection been wrong (I am using glRasterPos3fv).

Edit: Here is some code so far, it needs cleaning up, sorry. I have omitted the octree ray casting code as I'm not sure it's needed, but I will post if it'll help :)

```
void Draw(Vector cameraPosition, Vector cameraLookAt)
{
// Calculate the right Vector
Vector rightVector = Cross(cameraLookAt, Vector(0, 1, 0));

// Set up the screen plane starting X & Y positions
float screenPlaneX, screenPlaneY;
screenPlaneX = cameraPosition.x() - ( ( WINDOWWIDTH / 2) * rightVector.x());
screenPlaneY = cameraPosition.y() + ( (float)WINDOWHEIGHT / 2);

float deltaX, deltaY;
deltaX = 1;
deltaY = 1;

int currentX, currentY, index = 0;
Vector origin, direction;

origin = cameraPosition;
vector<Vector4<int>> colours(WINDOWWIDTH * WINDOWHEIGHT);

currentY = screenPlaneY;

Vector4<int> colour;

for (int y = 0; y < WINDOWHEIGHT; y++)
{
    // Set the current pixel along x to be the left most pixel
    // on the image plane
    currentX = screenPlaneX;

    for (int x = 0; x < WINDOWWIDTH; x++)
    {
        // default colour is black
        colour = Vector4<int>(0, 0, 0, 0);

        // Cast the ray into the current pixel. Set the length of the ray to be 200
        direction = Vector(currentX, currentY, cameraPosition.z() + ( cameraLookAt.z() * 200 ) ) - origin;
        direction.normalize();

        // Cast the ray against the octree and store the resultant colour in the array
        colours[index] = RayCast(origin, direction, rootNode, colour);

        // Move to next pixel in the plane
        currentX += deltaX;
        // increase colour arry index postion
        index++;
    }

    // Move to next row in the image plane
    currentY -= deltaY;
}

// Set the colours for the array
SetFinalImage(colours);

// Load array to 0 0 0 to set the raster position to (0, 0, 0)
GLfloat *v = new GLfloat[3];
v[0] = 0.0f;
v[1] = 0.0f;
v[2] = 0.0f;

// Set the raster position and pass the array of colours to drawPixels
glRasterPos3fv(v);
glDrawPixels(WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, finalImage);
}

void SetFinalImage(vector<Vector4<int>> colours)
{
    // The array is a 2D array, with the first dimension
    // set to the size of the window (WINDOW_WIDTH * WINDOW_HEIGHT)
    // Second dimension stores the rgba values for each pizel

    for (int i = 0; i < colours.size(); i++)
    {
        finalImage[i][0] = (float)colours[i].r;
        finalImage[i][1] = (float)colours[i].g;
        finalImage[i][2] = (float)colours[i].b;
        finalImage[i][3] = (float)colours[i].a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code and information on how the pixel data is stored in the array. glDrawPixels should be projection independent, but it depends on the settings from `glPixelStore`, `glPixelTransfer`, `glPixelMap` and `glPixelZoom`.

Comment: Hey, I have edited the original post with some source code. Now that I look over it, i think the problem may be how I set the length of the ray while calculating the ray direction in the for loop

Comment: Are you storing the color data in the same format that your draw() call expects (RGB, ARGB, RGBA, etc)?

Comment: A screenshot of the artifacting would help in determining the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pixel drawing code looks okay. But I'm not sure that your RayCasting routines are correct. When I wrote my raytracer, I had a bug that caused horizontal artifacts in on the screen, but it was related to rounding errors in the render code.

I would try this...create a result set of `vector<Vector4<int>>` where the colors are all red. Now render that to the screen. If it looks correct, then the opengl routines are correct. Divide and conquer is always a good debugging method.

Here's a question though....why are you using Vector4 when later on you write the image as `GL_FLOAT`? I'm not seeing any int->float conversion here....

Comment: Hmm, I dunno why I was using both floats and ints, I have changed that now. I did the above suggestion, and the colors do come out all red. However I think I'm not understading glDrawPixels. Because, if I move move towards the volume (in this case just a red plane), the plane becomes smaller. It's like the object is moving with the camera, if you understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: So, one thing to remember about glDrawPixels, it that it's pretty dumb. glDrawPixels completely ignores any sort of transformations etc. Basically you feed it a x/y location and it plasters the image to the screen. So if you want to clip the image, or do almost anything besides a straight blit to the screen, you'll want to use a texture and apply it to a polygon. 

Can you post a image? Surprisingly there are a large number of graphical errors that can be debugged simply by viewing the output image.

Comment: Ah ok, yeah that is probably the problem. I should use a texture instead then. Yeah here are some images. The original volume (done on the GPU) http://i130.photobucket.com/albums/p251/benzino07/originalVolume.png Here is rendered on the CPU with an octree http://i130.photobucket.com/albums/p251/benzino07/frame1.png (the octree is only level 2 or 3 here, but you can see it resembles the volume). But when I move towards the red box, you can see the volume also moves to http://i130.photobucket.com/albums/p251/benzino07/frame2.png I think this can be solved using a texture though.

Answer (score 0):

You problem may be in your 3DDDA (octree raycaster), and specifically with adaptive termination. It results from the quantisation of rays into gridcell form, that causes certain octree nodes which lie slightly behind foreground nodes (i.e. of a higher z depth) and which thus should be partly visible & partly occluded, to not be rendered at all. The smaller your voxels are, the less noticeable this will be.

There is a very easy way to test whether this is the problem -- comment out the adaptive termination line(s) in your 3DDDA and see if you still get the same gap artifacts.